I can't upgrade to ubuntu 24.04
I can't upgrade to ubuntu 24.04 so far while it's launched since many weeks ago.
it starts fine. then it asks for enabling third part sources
then it fails at (setting new software channels) second step
it shows me tab of error
then it cancels whole process


once I click ok on the error whole process gets canceled automatically
after trying to upgrade then failed I tried to reboot
this what it shows which I think it's the reason.
the shim signature.
I don't want to download ISO and do full format. I only want to upgrade


there is no version 24.10 as yet to upgrade to. Better off waiting for the first point release of 24.04.1 which should come in August.

sorry graham, I meant upgrading to 24.04. I can't upgrade to 24.04

Of course you verified the ISO you built the boot media from. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Does this answer your question? Can't upgrade to Kubuntu 24.04

hey David, I don't know how to do these steps. is there video showing me how to do them step by step. am not good at such tasks

what are you intending to upgrade from to 24.04?

am using Ubuntu 23.10. I want to upgrade whole system to 24.04. once I boot it shows me some issues about shim. it looks what David suggested up is related to my issue but how to do it? is there video explaining it?

ddoes this answer your question? https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/05/ubuntu-24-04-upgrades-officially-open

unfortuntely graham it doesn't help at all

I UPDATED THE SUBJECT. PLS GUYS, YOUR HELP

Since we don't have physical access to your system, it is very hard for us to help recover your system at this state. Please install Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch. You can use the live USB to backup data in your home folder.

This is a common problem and will effect everybody dual booting into Linux.  The reason is Microsoft is fiddling around with secure boot making it so that people booting into Linux will have problems.  I was able to get around it by following a couple posts of people having the same problem.  Here is the writeup I wrote on reddit about how to resolve this problem located here.
https://old.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/1euuha4/please_help_error_message_verifying_shim_sbat/

Ok the same thing just happened to me on a Dell Inspiron 17 3793 dual booting into Windows 10 and Ubuntu Mate, which is Ubuntu version 24.04. I booted into Windows 10 and it installed some updates. Everything seemed to be working but after a couple reboots I got the
"Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security policy violation Something went seriously wrong: SBAT self-test failed: Security Policy Violation"

Error message. Apparently Microsoft is setting up systems so that only certain bootloaders work. This effects everyone dual booting into Linux it appears. Ubuntu does work but you have to get the correct update via apt. I followed the instructions located here
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-self-check-failed-mitigating-the-impact-of-shim-15-7-revocation-on-the-ubuntu-boot-process-for-devices-running-windows/47378
Namely

Boot into your BIOS and disable secure boot, my bios key is f2 but sometimes they vary

NOTE: I was following a post on the Linux Mint forums which says to run this command

sudo mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=427297
The Ubuntu forums post does not say to run the mokutil command.  However I ran the above command first, rebooted, and it worked for me. Now you have to fix SBAT so that you can re-enable secure boot.

Boot into Ubuntu and run

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade shim-signed

Reboot, then Boot into Ubuntu AGAIN with secure boot still disabled and it will automatically cause the shim to reset the SBAT.

Reboot into the BIOS again and re-enable secure boot


Those steps worked for me. Man scary moment there as my keyboard failed a couple days earlier, which is why I rebooted into Windows, then this. Apparently the keyboard issue is potentially a hardware problem with some Dell laptops after a while. Mine is around 5 years old now, time to upgrade I guess. In the meantime I just attached an old USB keyboard and it appears to be working.
